# Making a frequency table from two columns based on a certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table with two columns titled "*Age*" and their preferred method of "*Choice*" (its just a dummy data, I have attached the picture on how it looks like). I want to make a frequency table in R out of it based on that should look something like

```
Choice       Age >= 40   Age < 40
Bio-metric   4          4
Manual       4          3
```

Any help is dearly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use `table` i.e. `with(df1, table(Choice, Age >=40))`

Comment: thanks a bundle man, it worked like a charm.. any idea on how to change the names of the column saying TRUE and FALSE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `table`.  Create a logical vector on the 'Age', recode it to numeric (`TRUE/FALSE` => `1/0`, `+1` => `2/1`, pass a new vector `c("Age < 40", "Age >=40"`) to make use of the index `1, 2` to change the values) and then apply the `table` along with 'Choice' column

```
with(df1, table(Choice, c('Age < 40', 'Age >=40')[1 +(Age >= 40)]))
```